# tor not connecting

Tags: windows

I've just started using the latest Tor Browser, connecting through my university connection. When I try to connect, it failed to establish connection with the network after waiting for a long time. I check the log and it says problem bootstrapping, stuck at 10%. My friend who uses Tor Browser and uses the same connection as me can connect to the network and use Tor Browser. We also use the same OS, Windows 8.1

tor log...help this out//

```
4/27/2016 7:45:12 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/27/2016 7:45:12 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/27/2016 7:45:12 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/27/2016 7:45:12 AM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:19 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:34 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:34 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:34 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:45:40 AM.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <BRIDGE IP> ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/27/2016 7:49:43 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/27/2016 7:49:43 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/27/2016 7:49:43 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: It looks like you're using bridges. Are you and your friend using the same bridges? (Also, please don't post the IP addresses of bridges in public forums.)